# WPF - Observable collection binding error

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I am tring to create a simple program that connect ObservableCollection to ListBox. I wrote:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> Values { get; set; }
```

and

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Values = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    Values.Add(1);
    DataContext = this;
}
```

then I was created button and wrote:

```
public Button1_Clicke(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Values.Add(2);
}
```

XMAL:

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values}"/>
```

When the window opened I able to see the '1' value.
But when I clicked the button, The list box dosent update the items. What is wrong?

Comment: That should work.  Add a messagebox to the click event with Values.Count

Comment: The size is getting bigger, but the list box doesnt update

Comment: If you want help you are going to need to post all you code.  This should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values}"/>
```

**EDIT:**
I have made a simple sample as below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>

        <ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values}"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Test"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Code behind (Window1.xaml.cs)

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> Values { get; set; }

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Values = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        Values.Add(1);
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Values.Add(2);
    }
}
```

It is working as expected. So base on your comments below why don't you try remove all of converter to make sure it correct or not.

Comment: So, are you make sure the button click call correct event you already posted here?

Comment: Quite strange, I cannot reproduce your problem. I run your code posted here and it working as expected. You should post the whole of your xaml to find out something.

Comment: I added dummy converter to the binding and it not called at all. And items still insertes to the observable collection.

Comment: So it doesn't make sense if value '2' don't appear into your listbox after you clicked the button.

Comment: How about ur environment? which version VS you are using? Windows version? and Net framework version as well.